# HourLocator() on yaxis raising runtime error unexpectedly exceeding Locator.MAXTICK

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying to setup a simple figure with some horizontal lines.

```
plt.figure()
plt.axhline(datetime.time(12,0,0,0),color='blue',ls='--',lw=3)
plt.axhline(datetime.time(18,0,0,0),color='red',ls='--',lw=3)
```

This works fine and I get:
[image]

which is correct.
Then I would like my yticks to be on the rounded hourly values only.
I am trying using HourLocator()

```
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter, 
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator()) # this fails
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

However, this generates this error.
Why is it trying to generate 570241  ticks?

`RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 570241 ticks from 42120.0 to 65880.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICK`S

Comment: `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator()) # this works fine` This is what actually fails with a runtimeError. Furthermore, what fails is not the `HourLocator`, but the `set_major_locator()`.

Comment: thx will fix the question

Comment: I'm quite sure that the issue comes from the fact it tries to label from 0001-01-01 UTC but I can't figure out how to fix it. sorry! It is just a matter of compatibility between the datetime used by matplotlib and the datetime you try to give...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that matplotlib does not support `datetime.time` values. Admittedly, the fact that it seemingly works hides this a bit.

So you first need to use `datetime.datetime` instead.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.axhline(datetime.datetime(2018,7,24,12,0,0,0),color='blue',ls='--',lw=3)
ax.axhline(datetime.datetime(2018,7,24,18,0,0,0),color='red',ls='--',lw=3)
ax.autoscale()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now this already gives you hourly ticks (by coincidence). But you may of course use custom locations and formats now, adding

```
from matplotlib.dates import HourLocator, DateFormatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator())
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

as in the question will give you the desired output.

[image]

Comment: while your answer work, in my case I really need to use datetime.time as values instead of datetime.datetime. Do you have any other solution without having to add a dummy date to datetime.time objects to make them datetime.datetime?

Comment: As said, matplotlib cannot understand `datetime.time` values. Maybe other plotting libraries can. However, I cannot think of any problem with adding a (random) date to the times; you may add more details as to why you think that you cannot use `datetime` objects.